# How do I turn a file into a RAW bitstring?

Tags: numpy, biginteger, bigint, hexdump, bitstring

How do I read a file and turn it to a RAW bit string? For example I open an image that is 512kb, It reads the file byte by byte, and it spits out the long bit string that is the file? I would like to apply some functions to the strings but I can't figure a way to unpack files consistently.

I imagine what I need is something that reads a file byte by byte with no care of the original file format... As it reads byte by byte, a giant integer like thing file bit string is created.

I used a Python's bit generator and NumPy, that seemed to work well, but The program didn't behave well with actual files. What is the best way to unpack files into 1's and 0's?

How do I read any file and store the contents as an easy to read HEX file? or BIN file? And how do I stop the "open" function from truncating leading 0's!

UGH!

Using Python or GOLANG, how do I open any file and create an uninterrupted bit string of the contents where every leading zero in a BYTE read is significant?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do but `x = int.from_bytes(file.read(), 'big')` will certainly give you a single integer`x` representing all the bytes of the file. You can then use the integer bit manipulation operators `>>, <<, &, |, ^` all you want. If you want an actual `str` representing the bits you can call `bin(x)`.

Comment: Something like that...

Take the code snippet:

f = open("Pro.mp4", "rb")

content = f.read()
print(content)

f.close()

that opens a file and reads the contents. How do i make the open function create an integer of it. Just a dump of 1's and 0's read, and spit out a single large HEX value for everything in the file? Ideally the open function should work despite file type.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: just use regex and perform large chunks of hex transcoding. (hint : all the decimal digits simply need to be prepended with %3 . e.g.   ASCII "7"becomes hex x37. When you're going over a large file, it's likely to be even more efficient to just loop through all 256-bytes (assuming the built-in functionality doesn't satisfy your needs) - the 16-chars in hex have 1:1 mapping to binary, so once you have ur hex dump, going to binary is almost trivial

Answer (score 0):

After looking and asking everyone I'm acquainted to I found my answer. The best way to turn any file into a RAW HEX string is by

```
f = open("file_name", "rb")
content = f.read().hex()
with open("File HEX bitstream.txt", "w") as text_file:
    print(f"HEX Bitstream Import", content, file=text_file)
f.close()
```